# How to set new query param to query string if not exists and request page with new url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data table. Rows of the table contain links. When I click on a link I have redirect to the same page but I will process the query parameter on the server. When I click on the second (another) link I will have URL with two query parameters. If I click on the same like twice I will not have a double.

To implement it I have this jQuery script:

```
$('table').find('a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let href = $(this).attr('href');
    href = href.replace(/^.+\?/u, '');
    let splitHref = href.split('=');

    let url = new URL(location.href);

    let queryString = url.search;

    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString); 

    if (splitHref[0] && splitHref[1]) {
        searchParams.append(splitHref[0], splitHref[1]);                    
    }

    url.search = searchParams.toString();

    let new_url = url.toString();

    console.log(new_url);
})
```

But it does not work. It gives me strange result like: `http://localhost:5000/Events?%3Fcustomerid=15787`. What is the  `%3F` after `?` char? And it can add only one linke or only replace one link. not append several links.

For better understanding this task I will show a screen of my UI:

[image]

After click by link I would like to have new query parameter.

Comment: The %3F is the questionmark character so you will have two question mark characteres this is how URL is encoded. You will need to check you code to see if you add additional question mark to the url

Comment: seems a problem with URL escaping.

Comment: yesss !! I have done it)) I'll share my solution as answer)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have done it! Here is example of the script. I appreciate any opinions.

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $('table').find('a').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = $(this).attr('href');
            href = href.replace(/^\?/u, '');

            let splitHref = href.split('=');

            let url = new URL(location.href);

            let queryString = url.search;

            let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString); 
            if (splitHref[0] && splitHref[1]) {
                searchParams.set(splitHref[0], splitHref[1]);                    
            }

            location.search = searchParams;       
        })
    })
</script>
```

The mistake was with `a` tags. Here is example of `a`:

```
<a href="?eventType=<here is a string with my value></a>
```

It was wrong reg exp. This is the example from the question:

```
 href = href.replace(/^.+\?/u, '');
```

Right regexp for this is

```
href = href.replace(/^\?/u, '');
```

I just replace `?`. The prev regexp does not work becouse of I don't have any symbols in in the start of the string, only `?`.